# Apple review notes

Tags: app-store-connect

So I have a couple of questions regarding what to write in the notes when submitting an app to the App store.

If my app will be entirely in Swedish, as well as only available in Sweden, should I write a translation to English for the text used inside of the app? If no, do I need to include a translation somewhere else?

If the reviewer needs an account to log in to the app, would they register one on their own or should I include a account in the notes? (there is a function both for login and registration inside the app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Account for Testing :- Yes you need to give test account for reviewing the build. Its not mandatory. But its good to give test account. It helps reviewer to review app easily.

In the **App Review Information** section you can provide this.

[image]

Regarding Localisation :- As per my knowledge there is no need to do so. They will review your app.